# Whats Wrong with this C++ Code Of Getline Function?

Tags: c++, c++11, getline

***When i input the Id , Name And Add . Id And Name are input successfully but,not Name.***

The Output shows Only Id And Name but, Name shows In Add Place.

Can anyone tell me **getline()** Function Of initialization Is Correct Or Not ?

```
  #include<iostream>
     using namespace std;
     class Stu_Record
     {
       private:
          int Id;
          char Name[20];
          char Add[20];

       public:
            void Input_Data();
            void Display_Data();

       };

           void Stu_Record::Input_Data()
           {
                cout<<endl<<"Enter Id,Name And Address:";
                cin>>Id;
                cin.getline(Name,20);
                cin.getline(Add,20);

           }

            void Stu_Record::Display_Data()
            {
                cout<<endl<<"Id Is :"<<ends<<Id;
                cout<<endl<<"Name Is :"<<ends<<Name;
                cout<<endl<<"Address Is :"<<ends<<Add;

            }

            int main()
            { 
                Stu_Record S;
                S.Input_Data();
                S.Display_Data();

                return(0);
             }
```

Comment: You don't need `cout << ends << Id`, just `cout << Id`. I also recommend prefixing all field use with `this->` for maintainability.

Comment: @Dai: Explicitly adding `this->` is not necessary, or even desirable in many cases. As long as you're not doing terrible things (like using global state variables), unqualified, undeclared names in a method can be assumed to be attributes, and prefixing them all with `this->` is just adding kruft. It's a reasonable personal style if that's your thing, but not worth suggesting as a "best practice".

Comment: Typing `this->` may lead to more typing defects (or typos).  Best not to use the syntax.

Answer (score 3):

`cin>>Id;` reads the `Id` in, but doesn't strip the newline that the user would have entered after it. The next call to `getline` sees that the next character is a newline, consumes it, and happily fills in `Name` as an empty string. The final `getline` then fills in what you expected to go to `Name` as the value of `Add` (and the value intended for `Add` is never read at all).

A simple fix would be to discard the rest of the line after reading in `Id`, so you don't have the garbage lying around when you try to read in `Name`. One way of doing that is [the `ignore` method on input streams](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore):

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

which will throw away everything following the data read to populate `Id` through to the next newline character, so if the user enters:

```
1 why did I type this garbage, oh the humanity
Fred
Where am I?
```

you'll get an `Id` of `1`, ignore the rest of the line, a `Name` of `"Fred"`, and an `Add` of `"Where am I?"`.

Comment: You can discard the one character after `Id` by adding a line `char e; cin.get(e);` right after `cin >> Id;`

Comment: @Steve That will fail if they enter a space after the ID before pressing Enter

Comment: @Steve: Or more thoroughly, use [the `ignore` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore), `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` to read and discard up through the next newline.